# $_POST - Cannot upload images larger than 1mb

Tags: php, post, upload

My webhosting service (Dreamhost) allows me to create a 'phprc' file and put custom variables in there:

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size= 64M
max_execution_time = 500
max_input_time = 500
memory_limit = 128M
```

I am certain the above code works as my phpinfo() file shows all the variables set as I want them to be.

However, whenever I use $_POST to try and upload images (all files are .jpg) larger than 1mb, I recieve a 413 error. The largest file I've successfully uploaded in 716kb, though I don't know any sizes of the failed ones.

The error I get:

```
Request Entity Too Large

The requested resource
/media/function-image-upload.php
does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data provided inthe request exceeds the capacity limit.
```

I've spent a long time trying to fix this, contacted support and done all sorts of things. I think there may be something wrong with the other variables in phpinfo().

I don't know what to do! :(

Comment: Do you have access to your apache config? Looks like you have issue similar to this option [httpd: LimitRequestBody](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody)

Comment: _“whenever I use $_POST to try and upload images larger than 1mb, I recieve a 413 error”_ - that might be coming from the web server itself, not PHP. So go check/read up on what limits they are imposing on the request size on web server configuration level.

Comment: http://www.doxbox.ca/index.php/forum/11-support/5463-cannot-upload-files-larger-than-500k.html mention apache 'modsecurity' and " SecRequestBodyLimit" as possiblely causing bother. I have no idea about it, just a result of a search.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks everybody, but it seems like it all was my mistake.

As it turns out, my host has mod_security enabled by default which was limiting the upload to 1mb. Turned that off and now everything works fine!

For future reference, or if anybody does have a problems like this and end up trawling the internet for HOURS to no avail:

SWITCH OFF MODSECURITY!

Special thanks Ryan Vincent for pointing it out, but I fixed it before muhaha :)

Comment: glad you got it sorted. :)

Comment: I am on dreamhost to and am getting the same error how do you turn off MODSECURITY?

Comment: Dreamhost indicate mod_security can be turned off by unchecking the box on their panel. They also helpfully point out that they don't support tweaking it via `.htaccess` (which renders many suggested fixes to this issue that would - essentially - turn off mod_security useless). For reference: https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215947927-How-do-I-enable-Extra-Web-Security-for-my-website-

Answer (score 0):

The max file upload size is a setting in `php.ini`, identified by `upload_max_filesize`.

Executing `cat /etc/php5/cli/php.ini | grep -i file_` on my 13.10 box returns

```
file_uploads = On
max_file_uploads = 20
upload_max_filesize = 5M //needs to be in {x}M format
```

This setting is typically set low by hosting providers to reduce bandwith and storage requirements.  Plus, when you think about it, you're an outlier when it comes to this since not many people need such large file uploads to a non web service such as Drive or Dropbox.

If you have access to the `php.ini` file, modifying it is simple.  If you don't, then I suggest you move your hosting plan to a VPS or use a Amazon AWS, linode droplet or heroku dyno.

Comment: The HTTP server ([Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody), [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#client_max_body_size), ...) has its own setting too. The maximum uploadable file size is thus the bottleneck of the maximum body size settings of the web stack